# python: can't open file 'test.py.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python

Всем привет

Вопрос:
Знаю Баян - но все же, не могу понять что происходит, подскажите.
Создал файл test.py
Запускаю CMD - выполняю путь D:\Python\python test.py
Ошибка:

```
D:\Python>python test.py
  File "test.py", line 1
    Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 22:45:29) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

Запускаю CMD

```
D:\Python>python test.py.py
python: can't open file 'test.py.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Команда DIR показала наличие самого файла:
04/11/2020  12:45 PM    <DIR>          ..
04/12/2020  10:52 AM               276 test.py
```

Переустановил Python, Windows - добавил PATH
Благодарю

Comment: Проверьте для начала путь к файлу.

Comment: Во втором примере у вас лишнее расширение у файла

Comment: У вас имя файла test.py или test.py.py

Comment: А в первом непонятно что за ошибка вообще, где текст ошибки?

Comment: Файл находится в D:Python
Сохранял как test и пробовал как test.py
-1 вариант 
D:\Python>python test.py
  File "test.py", line 1
    Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 22:45:29) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

-DIR:
04/12/2020  10:52 AM               276 test.py
-2 вариант
D:\Python>python test.py
python: can't open file 'test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

-DIR
Directory of D:\Python
04/12/2020  10:52 AM               276 test.py.py

Comment: Вы ищите файл test.py.py, а есть у вас test.py. Найдите отличия и исправьте код.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш файл `python.py` очевидно имеет как первую строку текст

```
Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 22:45:29) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

*Это просто не правильная команда Питона!*

Уберите эту строку из вашего файла, или сделайте ею комментарием (символом `#` перед ней).

---

*Доказательство:*

Когда я запускаю файл `test.py` с этим текстом в первой строке (командой `python test.py`), получаю, как и вы, ошибку

> ```
>   File "test.py", line 1
>     Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 22:45:29) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
>              ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

---

*Примечание:*

Как эта строка появилась в вашем файле?

1. Вы скопировали код с какой-то книги.
2. Вы скопировали код с Питон-консоли программы *PyCharm,* где эта информационная строка стандартно является первым выводом.
3. ??? (не знаю).

Comment: Все отлично, получилось!
Я когда открыл IDLE - сохранял в первоначальном окне( или как оно называется)
А нужно было сделать new file и сохранить его с того окна.

Огромное спасибо!